# Converting Java code to Kotlin for ironsource reward video listener

Tags: java, kotlin, ironsource

ı need help with converting Java code to Kotlin. It is specifically for rewardVideoListener section of ironsource. Can you help me? Autoconverting didn't start unfortunately. Looked for an answer in the internet but there was none.

```
IronSource.setRewardedVideoListener(new RewardedVideoListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAvailabilityChanged(boolean available) {
        //Change the in-app 'Traffic Driver' state according to availability.
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdShowFailed(IronSourceError error) {
    }
    
    @Override
   public void onRewardedVideoAdClicked(Placement placement){
   }
    
     @Override
     public void onRewardedVideoAdStarted(){
     }
   
    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdEnded(){
    }
});
```

Comment: Q: Is nobody interested in writing Java for Android anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it

```
IronSource.setRewardedVideoListener(object : RewardedVideoListener {
            override fun onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {}
            override fun onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {}
            override fun onRewardedVideoAvailabilityChanged(available: Boolean) {}
            override fun onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(placement: Placement) {}
            override fun onRewardedVideoAdShowFailed(error: IronSourceError) {}
            override fun onRewardedVideoAdClicked(placement: Placement) {}
            override fun onRewardedVideoAdStarted() {}
            override fun onRewardedVideoAdEnded() {}
        })
```